# How learn to create a (virtual) graphic driver for Windows?

Tags: windows, driver, directx

I would like to try for educational purposes to create a graphic driver for Windows executed in a virtual machine able to show the display in a window on the host OS but also able to rendering basic DirectX instructions, using a proxy application always on the host that gives the commands to the effective GPU.

Yes, I guess that the last part begins to be pretty complicated, but here the things makes interesting. What documentations I have to look for learning how develop a virtual graphic driver?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: https://github.com/roshkins/IddSampleDriver

This is a sample driver that shows how to create a Windows Indirect Display Driver using the IddCx class extension driver.